# Alert value of a link in a table-cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAL7L/1/).
It shows two headlines and two tables with table-cells.
What I'm trying to do is to alert the values in the table-cells below one headline when clicking a headline.

Example:
If one clicks on Headline1 there should be an alert with the values 5 and 2.
If one clicks on Headline2 there should be an alert with the value 6.

My problem is that I don't get the values.
Have you got an idea?

Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: First of all, I'd say you need to combine the `table` and `div` with some ID or so, so as to be able to reference to the correct table.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get all values until the next div? E.g. with nextUntil(). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".bold").click(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $(this).next().find('a').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });
    alert(arr.join(', '));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAL7L/13/

Comment: Could you explain perhaps why you search for `td` also? I removed it and still worked fine.

Comment: There was no particular reason. I guess it's cleaner without it, so good spot.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest altering the markup. Otherwise I think you'll have a hard time getting the result you want.

HTML:

```
    <div class="bold">Headline1
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">5</a></td>
        <td><a href="">2</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="bold">Headline2
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="">6</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

then your javascript could look like this:

```
$(".bold").click(function() {$(this).find("a").each(function(){alert($(this).html());}); });
```

I'm not saying it's the best solution - but it works ;-)